# How do I get the text to align to the top of the space that it takes up?

Tags: html, css

I've tried messing with `vertical-align`, `line-height`, etc.

[image]

should show you what I'm trying to do. I put a little red arrow to show where I want the text shifted up to.

Comment: It is aligned top in the space you have provided for it, you have a margin top, remove the margin-top?

Comment: I wanted the top of it aligned with the gray box to the left of it

Comment: That is how it is right now, where is the problem?

Comment: I've updated my answer, it looks like you only need to move your h2 tag up by about 5px. Any one of the examples I provided will get you there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to modify the top margin in css or html, below are three ways of doing so.

**edit in css:**

```
h2 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

**edit inline style in html:**

`<h2 style="margin-top="20px;">` remove "margin-top" from inline style

**override inline style:**

if you don't have access to your html you can override the inline style:

```
h2[style] {

margin-top: 0px;

}
```

Update:

Based on your comment on your OP, it looks like you only want to move your text up about **5px**. you may want to use something like `margin: 15px` or `margin: 20px` to line your text up with the top of the grey box. The examples above still apply.

Comment: Good pickup on the inline styles used.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an `h2` tag surrounding the text. You should override the margin for that particular class in this fashion:

```
h2 {
margin-top:0;
}
```

If you wish to only target the text in that particular `div` you should specify that in your css like so:

```
#this-div h2 {
margin-top:0;
}
```

**EDIT**

As you are using inline styles in your html (which I personally tend to avoid) you will have to modify the inline styles of your h2 tag within your html to achieve the results you desire.